# ORA-01843 Not a valid Month error for to_timestamp(CURRENT_DATE,'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF')

Tags: sql, oracle19c

I am getting this error on few Oracle 19c DB environments while it runs on another when executing insert query for a the same table having same column signature. The error I get is ORA-01843 Not a valid Month error for inserting to_timestamp(CURRENT_DATE,'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF') into a TIMESTAMP(6) NON Nullable column.

Wondering if it has got anything to do with how CURRENT_DATE displays on both the DB. I tested the same on SQL developer and I get the same output.

Comment: This is an issue with the *data* being inserted. At least one record's text of `current_date` does not match the format (specifically a valid month month) of `DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF`. What data type *is* `current_date`? Your statement implies text, like `varchar2`.

Comment: This is an oracle function which I guess is sensitive to session timezone which might be the issue. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CURRENT_DATE.html#GUID-96795097-D6F0-4288-90E7-9D7C49B4F6E5

Comment: The error is specific: the data being inserted doesn't represent a valid *month* that matches the filter 'MON'. That is not a timezone issue. If the source data is a character field (as implied by your use of TO_TIMESTAMP), then you have badly formatted data that needs correction.

Answer (score 0):

- The `CURRENT_DATE` function generates a `DATE` data type.
- `TO_TIMESTAMP(string_value, format_model, nls_settings)` takes a string as the first argument.

Therefore, your query:

```sql
to_timestamp(CURRENT_DATE,'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF')
```

Will try to convert the `DATE` to a string so that it is the correct data type for the function and will use the current NLS session parameters in the conversion and then `TO_TIMESTAMP` will convert it back from a string to a `TIMESTAMP`. So your query is implicitly converted to:

```sql
to_timestamp(
  TO_CHAR(
    CURRENT_DATE,
    ( SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
  ),
  'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF'
)
```

If the NLS session parameter does not match your format model `DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF` then the query will fail. If it does match then it may succeed (or it may "work" but give unexpected results).

---

What you should do is either:

- Use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (rather than `CURRENT_DATE`);
- Directly convert the data types using:

  ```sql
  CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS TIMESTAMP)
  ```

  (rather than trying to use `TO_TIMESTAMP` and converting to-and-from strings);
- Explicitly convert the date to a string rather than relying on implicit conversions

  ```sql
  TO_TIMESTAMP(
    TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SS'),
    'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SS'
  )
  ```

  (Note: you can add `XFF` to the timestamp format model but the date will never have any fractional seconds so this part of the format model would always be ignored); or
- Change the NLS session parameters so that the implicit string conversion works:

  ```sql
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS';
  ```

  (Note: while this would work, you should not use it and should fix your query so that it does not rely on implicit string conversions using one of the previous options.)